# Does A∪C=B∪C imply A = B? What about intersection instead of union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples

if A, B and C are sets; 
for (u = union, n = intersection)

> $A \cup C = B \cup C$, would $A = B$ ?

Similar for

> $A \cap C = B \cap C$, would $A = B$ ?

For my conclusion I have got for the first one, $A \neq B$ because $A$ can contain values differently from $B$ and for the second one $A$ does equal to $B$. Is this correct?

Comment: 1) is ok but the argument is not comprehensible. For 2) you are wrong. See my post below.

Comment: The first question seems rather similar to this post: [If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets, the only way that $A\cup C = B \cup C$ is if $A=B$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575065/if-a-b-and-c-are-sets-the-only-way-that-a-cup-c-b-cup-c-is-if-a-b)

Comment: The second question is similar to this one: [Proving $A \cap C = B \cap C$, but $ A \neq B$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660315/proving-a-cap-c-b-cap-c-but-a-neq-b)

Comment: And in the context of your question, this post is interesting, too: [Prove that $A=B$ considering: $(A \cap C = B \cap C) \land (A \cup C = B \cup C)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742606/prove-that-a-b-considering-a-cap-c-b-cap-c-land-a-cup-c-b-cup-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what quantification you do on $C$. If the premise is true for all sets $C$ then your conclusion holds, not if it's a specific unfortunate set.

To see why this is the case in the first interpretation you can choose $C$ to be a fortunate set. If we have $C=A\cap B$ in the first equation and $C=A\cup B$ in the second:

$A = A \cup (A \cap B) = B \cup (A \cap B) = B$

$A = A \cap (A \cup B) = B \cap (A \cup B) = B$

However if the premises don't hold for any set $C$ we may be unfortunate with the value $C$ has. In the first equation we could have that $C = A\cup B$ for the first equation and $C = A \cap B$ for the second and we would have regardles of $A$ and $B$ (which could be unequal):

$A \cup C = A \cup (A \cup B) = A\cup B = B \cup (A\cup B) = B \cup C$

$A \cap C = A \cap (A \cap B) = A \cap B = B \cap (A \cap B) = B \cap C$

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct in the first case. But to be complete you need to give an example. Consider the sets

$A=\{1,2\},$ $B=\{2,3\}$ and $C=\{1,2,3\}.$ It is $A\cup B=A\cup C=C=\{1,2,3\}.$ However, $A\ne B.$

For the second case, consider $A=\{1,2\},$ $B=\{2,3\}$ and $C=\{2\}.$ It is $A\cap B=A\cap C=C=\{2\}.$ But, $A\ne B.$

Comment: You have a typo in the last sentence
$B \neq C$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$1)$ Look what happen if $A\neq B$ and $A,B\subset C$.

$2)$ Look what happen if $A\neq B$ and $A,B\supset C$.

Comment: What ???? 1) $A\neq B$ ! You said it in your post and I told you it was correct. Why do you want that $A=B$ now ? 2) Yes, $A\neq B$. I gave you all the the elements you need to prove those two assertions !

Comment: I had misread what you wrote, but understand it now, I am proving it now. Just don't know how to prove the second, do you have any tips on that one? As for your hint, what is that ⊃ symbol you have used?

Comment: $A,B\supset C$ mean that $A$ and $B$ contain $C$.